# Issues in binary files

Tags: binary

1. I am storing variable sized records in a binary file. Hence, i want to demarcate each record. What is a good demarcation symbol for records in a binary file?
2. How would you do a binary search on a binary file?
3. Are there any search algorithms on binary files?

Binary file in my case primarily means numerical values, adhering to binary spec. A value stored in 3 bits, followed by value stored in 25 bits and so on...

Comment: 4. what's a binary file?

Comment: @Bozho - I guess, not human-readable ASCII-text based. Of course, yes, they're all binary.

Answer (score 0):

1. A better solution is storing the length of the record. If you can't do that just pick a separator that you know can't be present in normal data.
2. Binary search with records in a binary file works just like you with any data. Remember that the records have to be sorted.
3. Good search algorithms for binary data - to search what? Generic text search algorithms work just fine if you are trying to match a pattern.

Answer (score -1):

1) There isn't one.
2) I'm just.. look, you can't.
3) Sequential comparison.